# Hosting web application on windows server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, hosting

Hi guys i have created a web application in asp.net as front end and MS-SQL as back end.I hosted this web application on windows 7 and it is working fine. I have used report viewer handler in my application to use SSRS reports this is my handler

```
 <handlers>
  <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
</handlers>
```

And now my boss wants it on winodws server 2008 R2 i tried to host application there but it is giving me "HTTP Error 500.19" error with HResult code 0x80070021.The error says cannnot read handler so when i comment the handler tag in config my application runs fine but then my SSRS report gives a error.
 I tried adding handler through IIS then too my SSRS report gives an error.
  I also changed value from "Deny" to "Allow" in %windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\ applicationHost.config in

```
            <section name="handlers" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />

<section name="modules" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" overrideModeDefault="Deny"/>
```

But still same error comes.Does anyone knows how to slove this ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates a malformed XML element or config error, and this link may help with your config settings:

[Web.config Settings for ReportViewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251661.aspx)